# What's the anatomy of a DNS session?

Tags: c, dns, netcat

I'm working on a homework assignment that basically asks us to parse a DNS response to get the IP address and such. The problem is the professor has told us in great detail what the response looks like from the DNS server, but I don't know what to send the server. My first attempt was to `netcat <ip address of local name server> 53` and just type in www.google.com and hit enter and look for a response but I didn't get anything back.

Can anyone describe to me what a DNS query looks like (like how many bytes are allowed for each part of the query)?

Comment: I bet using your favourite search engine would be quite productive.

Comment: I've already gone through google searches but all of their answers have to do with using predefined DNS functions in C which we aren't allowed to use for this assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download wireshark, and run it
2. Do something that uses DNS (make sure you aren't using a cached hostname)
3. Look through the wireshark packets that are captured.

Comment: -1 for recommending reverse engineering as an approach to implementing a standardized protocol with a published specification (RFC 1035)

Comment: I don't have time to peruse an RFC. Wireshark worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: Do both (read the RFP and look at packets).  Have you looked at WireShark -- you don't have to reverse engineer it -- it parses it for you -- way easier than reading code or the RFP.  After looking at it, you can understand the RFP much better.

Answer (score 4):

This should be covered by [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt), section 3.7, but I kind of glazed over just skimming it, let alone actually reading the thing.

Comment: I believe it's 1035 you want for the protocol.

Comment: don't forget also to look at 1101, 1183, 1348, 1876, 1982, 2065, 
2181, 2308, 2535, 4033, 4034, 4035, 4343, 4592, 5936 that update the rfc http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034 and 1995, 1996, 2136, 2137, 2845, 3425, 3658, 5966 for http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035 Wireshark is a valuable tool to see what actually is going on.

Comment: I would not recommend the rest of those to someone just wanting to act as a DNS "client" and perform lookups, except perhaps to find the numeric value of RR type AAAA. They're mostly of interest to someone implementing a DNS server or recursive lookups, not basic client use of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The basic shape of a DNS query is a short header that's essentially all fixed byte values, followed by what you'd get if you took the name, prefixed it with a dot (`.`), then replaced each dot with a byte in the range 1-63 indicating the length of the following segment of the name up to the next dot, followed by some more fixed-value bytes. As long as all you're doing is basic address lookups and nothing fancy like zone transfers, this is about all you need to know about DNS protocol.

For details of the header, etc. fields, read RFC 1035. Or just copy them from a packet sniffer dump. The only thing you'll want to vary is the query id (it should be suitably random to avoid trivial spoofing attacks against your program), and possibly the RR type (for instance if you need to query IPv6 (AAAA) or reverse DNS (PTR) records in addition to just A.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt directly answer your question, but try running nslookup for the commandline and look at the options available. You can instruct it to query for specific items, such as the MX records etc.

But if you are more interested in what the protocol itself looks like? this RFC has way more info than you could possibly want: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035